# HTML/CSS: 10x10 div boxes with equal margin, but height is longer than width for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jchjuckp/

imgur clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC8ol.png

I created in JavaScript a 10x10 grid (div boxes), and each box has 5px margin. I expected a perfect square to come out, but for some reason, the distance between each Y-axis box is 13 pixels instead of 10 px (because 5px margin + 5px margin = 10px).

Some CSS code snippet:

```
.sketchbox {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
}

br {
  line-height: 0px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the line break im using, but every CSS I do to try to change line break to 0px has had no effect.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `vertical-align` property of the `inline-block` element. In this case, `.sketchbox`.

You could try `vertical-align: top`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwzqe63t/)

```
.sketchbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

When the value is `baseline` (the default), there is a reserved vertical space for letters such as j, q, y.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know such a property existed, but it does make sense. Your solution works perfectly!